# Cover Page not rendering on Safari

Tags: html, css, mobile, pingendo

[image]
On the website (https://harshulshuk.github.io), content on the cover page does not render properly on Safari or Chrome but works correctly on Firefox. A lot of the code was generated with the application Pingendo, so I didn't write a majority. Anything at the bottom of the CSS is mine. Any ideas?

Note: I am specifically trying to get the mobile 'size' working, so when looking at the site, shorten the width (on a computer browser) until the background flips to vertical. In the image provided, Firefox is on the left, Safari is on the right.

Also Note: I figured it was easier to just do Inspect Element on the site itself than post a lot of the code here. I can change this if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [PrefixFree](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/), this helps in putting the right prefixes for the right browser, that might fix your problem.